# Difference between moment.utc(date) and moment(date).utc()

Tags: javascript, momentjs, utc

Trying to understand the behaviour and difference between:

`moment.utc(date) and moment(date).utc()`

Using '2018-05-31' as a param:

`moment.utc('2018-05-31').format()` will give:

> ‌2018-05-31T00:00:00Z

while `moment('2018-05-31').utc().format()` will give:

> 2018-05-31T04:00:00Z

I am executing both in EST timezone.

Comment: The former gives UTC midnight. The latter converts your local midnight into UTC. (I'm at GMT+2, the 2nd gives `2018-05-30T22:00:00Z`)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The first [`moment.utc(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) parses your string as UTC, while the latter **converts** your moment instance to UTC mode.

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`.
>
> This brings us to an interesting feature of Moment.js. UTC mode.

See [Local vs UTC vs Offset](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/) guide to learn more about UTC mode and local mode.

```js
console.log( moment.utc('2018-05-31').format() );
console.log( moment('2018-05-31').utc().format() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```